# Adding Raspberry Pi Hat edge-cuts and holes in Kicad (after schematic capture)

Tags: raspberry-pi, kicad

I'm looking for a way (in KiCad 5x) to build a Raspberry Pi HAT around a design that has already been completed.  That is, I did not start with a Pi Hat TEMPLATE ... I hope to find a way to add it after the (schematic capture) phase. I need edge cuts , hole placement and connector alignment that is known to be correct. I see its easy if you start with a Pi HAT TEMPLATE but I need to get the dimensions right AFTER the design is completed. How could I do this in KiCAd?

Answer (score 3):

Open `pcbnew` as a stand-alone application and load your completed board file.

Then, from the file menu, select "Append Board"

[image: File:Append Board]

Navigate to the location where your templates are stored.  For me, that is `/usr/local/share/kicad/template/` but it may be different on your system.  You can find where by looking at the path in the "Preferences -> Configure Paths" menu.

[image: Select Raspberry PI hat template]

Select and open the `raspberrypi_hat.kicad_pcb` file.

This will import everything from the file.  You will want to delete the extra components.  Align your existing design with the connector and you should be set.

[image: PI Hat template]